# Number combination with groups and the smallest repetition possible

Tags: permutations

I need to create a equation to assign a number of phrases (variable A) to a a defined number of groups (variable B) and repeat these assignment each day, and repeat this operation along of time with the smallest (or most distant) repetition possible.

Some info: the start date is 01/01/1970.
The language is PHP, but the question is the mathematical formula.

The big problem is when the phrases number is not a multiple of groups.

Example of results to 5 phrases to 3 groups.
(remember that the groups and phrases is a variable)

```
|date     |G1 |G2 |G3 |
|:-------:|:-:|:-:|:-:|
|22/01/14 | 1 | 2 | 3
|23/01/14 | 4 | 5 | 1
|24/01/14 | 2 | 3 | 4
|25/01/14 | 5 | 1 | 2
|26/01/14 | 3 | 4 | 5
|27/01/14 | 1 | 2 | 3
|28/01/14 | 4 | 5 | 1
|29/01/14 | 2 | 3 | 4
|30/01/14 | 5 | 1 | 2
|31/01/14 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

Example of results to 8 phrases to 3 groups.

```
|date     |G1 |G2 |G3 |
|:-------:|:-:|:-:|:-:|
|22/01/14 | 1 | 2 | 3
|23/01/14 | 4 | 5 | 6
|24/01/14 | 7 | 8 | 1
|25/01/14 | 2 | 3 | 4
|26/01/14 | 5 | 6 | 7
|27/01/14 | 8 | 1 | 2
|28/01/14 | 3 | 4 | 5
|29/01/14 | 6 | 7 | 8
|30/01/14 | 1 | 2 | 3
|31/01/14 | 4 | 5 | 6
|01/02/14 | 7 | 8 | 1
|02/02/14 | 2 | 3 | 4
|03/02/14 | 5 | 6 | 7
|04/02/14 | 8 | 1 | 2
|05/02/14 | 3 | 4 | 5
|06/02/14 | 6 | 7 | 8
```

Example of results to 6 phrases to 2 groups.

```
|date     |G1 |G2 |
|:-------:|:-:|:-:|
|22/01/14 | 1 | 2
|23/01/14 | 3 | 4
|24/01/14 | 5 | 6
|22/01/14 | 2 | 3
|23/01/14 | 4 | 5
|24/01/14 | 6 | 1
```

Example of results to 5 phrases to 2 groups.

```
|date     |G1 |G2 |
|:-------:|:-:|:-:|
|22/01/14 | 1 | 2
|23/01/14 | 3 | 4
|24/01/14 | 5 | 1
|22/01/14 | 2 | 3
|23/01/14 | 4 | 5
|24/01/14 | 1 | 2
|25/01/14 | 3 | 4
|26/01/14 | 5 | 1
|27/01/14 | 2 | 3
|28/01/14 | 4 | 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that your example with $6$ phrase and $2$ groups do exact that. (But I see what you want to avoid)

Also, I know that you mentioned that both $A$ and $B$ are variables, but you didn't mention if you can access/modify this parameter before or during the use of the function (pointers for example).

Because of that, I will try both alternatives.

My first suggestion (and the easiest solution) to work around the problem would be to decline multiple (or to convert them into non multiples)

You could do this by adding some kind of control outside the function like:

```
IF (numphrases%numgroups == 0)

    numphrases +=;
```

Or

```
IF (numphrases%numgroups == 0 AND numgroups > 1)

    numgroups -=;
```

However, since I don't know much about the project, it is possible that you don't have this option.

In this case, there is a problem with this "shift" in circular permutations that will repeat every $k \equiv 1 \; \textrm{mod} \; \frac{p}{g}$ by $k$ meaning the position.

Examples:

```
               2 groups 4 phrases                 3 groups 9 phrases

Position 1            1   2                             1  2  3

Position 2            3   4                             4  5  6

Position 3            4   1 <-Need shift (p/g+1)        7  8  9

Position 4            2   3                             8  9  1 <-Shift (p/g+1)

Position 5            ?   ? <-Need shift (p/g+1)        2  3  4

Position 6            ?   ?                             5  6  7

Position 7            ?   ?                             ?  ?  ? <-Shift (p/g+1)
```

It doesn't matter if the "shift" is done forward or backward.

However, the maximum number of "shift's" allowed before we repeat the circle is $g-1$ and the number of "shift's" done at a given position $k$ will be the integer result of $\frac{\textrm{days passed}}{\textrm{numgroups}}$.

Since every $g-1$ the circle repeat, we can define the "shift's" as $s_{1}, s_{2}, \dots, s_{g-1}$ where $s_{i}$ means we shifted the circle by $i$ positions.

In this case, without knowing nothing about the range of possible values of $A$ and $B$, my suggestion (that need to be tested) is:

```
int RETURNPHRASE(day, numberofgroups, group, numphrases)

    int numshifts, dayspassed;

    numshifts = 0;

    dayspassed = day - STARTDAY;

    /* Need to implement a GCD function that returns the Greatest common

    *  divisor between two numbers */

    if((numphrases%numberofgroups !=0) && (GCD(numphrases,numgroups) !=0))
    {   
        I = day - startday #number of days that had passed

        F = (I * numberofgroups)%numphrases

        return (F+group-1)%numphrases
    }

    if(GCD(numphrases,numgroups) !=0)

    {

        numshifts = dayspassed / numgroups;

        numshifts %= (numgroups - 1);

        F = ((I * numberofgroups)%numphrases)+numshifts)%numphases

        return (F+group-1)%numphrases

    }

    /* Need to implement a lcm (Least common multiple) also */

    numshifts = dayspassed / (LCM(numgroups,numphrases)/numgroups

    numshifts %= (numgroups - 1)

    F = ((I * numberofgroups)%numphrases)+numshifts)%numphases

    return (F+group-1)%numphrases
```

I think that will handle the shifts. However, if you could give more details about the range of possible values of $A$ and $B$ maybe there is a better solution.

I adjusted the function to get the problems you mentioned. (Unfortunately couldn't look the adjusts you made yet)

However, you will need a gcd and lcm functions in the code which I only called without concerns about the implementation.

Comment: 1) You are right, I edit the 6 phrase and 2 groups to start the day 4th day with phrase 2 to group 1.
2) I do NOT need to modify the parameters before or during the use of the function. I ran several instances of the function with different parameters, but not change the parameters in each context.

Comment: Great Décio! I do some little change in the code and now works with the shift system in the case of numphrases%numberofgroups = 0 ... 1) numshifts = floor(dayspassed / (numphrases / numgroups)) ... 2) numshifts %= numphrases ... can you revise please if is correct?

Comment: Another problem! .. try to execute the algorithm with 4 groups and 14 phrases ... After 7 days I have a exactly repetition. I believe that the shift must occurs in others situations.

Comment: You are right, every time the numbers are not coprimes (gcd(numgroups, numphrases) $\neq 1$) you will get a repetition in the position ($\textrm{lcm}$(numgroups,numphrases)/numgroups)+1. Ex. $\textrm{lcm}(4,14)/4=28/4=7$ repetition in 8th position; $\textrm{lcm}(6,10)/6=30/6=5$ repetition in 6th position. You need to make the shift in those cases also.

Comment: Finally! I believe that all problems are resolved. I write the function in PHP and works perfectly! Thank you so much Décio! A very beautiful solution, you have very strong knowledge in math! And sorry for my wrong english LoL. Depois te pago uma cerveja! :)

Comment: It's good to know it worked. About the english nothing to worry about, we are at the same boat :). Com relação a cerveja, no próximo happy hour pelo menos tome uma por mim. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define what you mean by repetition.  If you mean reuse of a phrase between groups, you are doing fine.  If there are $p$ phrases and $g$ groups, each phrase comes back on average after $\frac pg-1$ cycles.  Note that your assignments repeat every $g$ days.  Is that acceptable?  It gets harder if (in the first example) you don't want to repeat all three assignments on $27/01/14$  There are a total of $60$ assignments in this case and you only run through $5$ of them.

If you want a formula for which phrase a group gets on a given day, let us count the first day as day zero.  Then on day $d$ group 1 gets phrase $gd+1 \pmod p$ and group $n$ gets phrase $gd+n \pmod p$

Seeing the update to $p=6, g=2$ and assuming the next day starts with $3$, you can do this.  If $g$ divides evenly into $p$ you have a bump every $\frac pg$ days so the relation will be that group $n$ gets phrase $gd + n + \lfloor \frac {ng}p \rfloor \pmod p$

Comment: Hi Ross. Thank you! Good explanation. Sorry for my wrong mathematical terms. The repetition is accepted and required, because these phrases are sent each day in several years, but, the most distance as possible. The repeat all three assignments on 27/01 is not a problem.

Comment: If is possible, is important that the phrases are in "sequences" like the two examples. Is acceptable the "shift" of values after a cycle to maintain the "most distance as possible" of phrases.

Comment: Is important that in each cycle, each group has different phrases, and in each day the phrases are differents.

Comment: Then what problem do you see with what you have?  It looks fine to me based on what you have said.

Comment: The problem is to create a equation to reproduce these examples. I need to write a function in PHP with this equation. The input is the day, the group and the number of phrases. The output is the prhase number.

Comment: Ok, if the p is not multiple of g in p days I don't have repetitions of phrases in each group. But, if the p is multiple of g, the problem is that the phrases of groups in day d is identical of phrases in d = p / g. Only when is multiple, I need to 'shift' (by x) the phrases to get unique phrases in each group in p days.

Comment: Taking your example of $p=6,g=2$ after the third day you could start counting at $2$ instead of $1$.  Is that the sort of pattern you are looking for?

Comment: You are right, the thrid day start with 2. I edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that the phrases are not allowed to repeat itself in the same day. (Ex. |22/01/14 | 1 | 1 | 1 is not possible).

Also, I will assume that you can establish a relation between the variable $A$ and the first $n$ phrases.

So, let $g_{i}$ be the result of $i$th group in a given day, $p$ the number of phrases and $n$ the number of groups.

The minimum value for $\sum_{i=1}^{n} g_{i}=\dfrac{(n+1) \cdot n}{2}$ where $n$ is the number of groups.

On the other hand, the maximum value for $\sum_{i=r-n+1}^{r} g_{i}=\dfrac{(2r-n+1) \cdot n}{2}$

To use your first example, considering that repetition are not allowed, the minimum value of $g_{1}+g_{2}+g_{3}=1+2+3=6$ and the maximum value are $g_{1}+g_{2}+g_{3}=3+4+5=12$.

With that in mind, you can use recursion to make the following:

I) Permute all the possible non-negative values of the diophantine equation:
$$
g_{1}+g_{2}+\dots +g_{g}=k
$$

Where $k = \dfrac{(n+1) \cdot n}{2}$.

That will give you with $\dbinom{k-1}{g-1}$ minus the values where we possible had repeated values.

In the example:

> |22/01/14 | 1 | 2 | 3
>
> |23/01/14 | 1 | 3 | 2
>
> |24/01/14 | 2 | 1 | 3
>
> |25/01/14 | 2 | 3 | 1
>
> |26/01/14 | 3 | 1 | 2
>
> |27/01/14 | 3 | 2 | 1

Note that by the formula you had $\dbinom{5}{2}=10$ and we only got $6$ because we had to remove $\left\{ (2,2,2);(1,1,4);(1,4,1);(4,1,1) \right\}$

II) Increment $k$ by 1 and repeat the process.

III) Do that while $k \leq \dfrac{(2r-n+1) \cdot n}{2}$

Following this algorithm you will be able to get all possible values without repeat.

However, for (I) you will had to implement a function that find the possible results of a diophantine equation.

Edit:

Since you just want to reproduce your example, note that what are you doing is a circular permutation. Let $P(\textrm{days passed})$ denote the first element that start your sequence.

Suppose that you had $g$ groups and $p$ phrases. Then, let 01/01/1970 be defined as day $1$:

$$
\begin{matrix}
P(1) = 1; \\
P(2) = P(1) + g \; \textrm{mod} \; p = g+1 \; \textrm{mod} \; p;\\
P(3) = P(2) + g \; \textrm{mod} \; p = 2g+1 \; \textrm{mod} \; p;\\
\vdots \\
P(n) = (n-1)g+1 \; \textrm{mod} \; p
\end{matrix}
$$

So, in order to get the phrase number in the sequence you had to do:

> int RETURNPHRASE(day, numberofgroups, group, numphrases)
>
> > I = day - startday #number of days that had passed
> >
> > F = (I * numberofgroups)%numphrases
> >
> > return (F+group-1)%numphrases

From F you can get any $g_{i}$ since it is the first one in the sequence.

You need to adjust the algorithm for PHP but I think the main idea is there.

Comment: Obrigado Décio. But is important that the phrases are unique in each group in a cycle. Like Example 1 from 22/01/2014 and 26/01/2014. In this cycle the phrases not repeats in each group and the phrases not repeat in each day. And is important that all phrases are used in all groups. Not that the cycle is p (phrases) days.

Comment: In your example the phrase 1 is used in two consecutive days, is important that this repetition occurs only after p (phrases) days.

Comment: Edited to include an algorithm to reproduce your example.

Comment: Wow! Great! ... But I believe that is missing the group number as input to the function, because I need to know the phrase to each group in each day.

Comment: Edited to include the group as parameter.

Comment: Perfect!!! Worked like a charm! Thank you very much Décio!!! A great response to the question, simple and beautiful!

Comment: Ops ... only one problem. When and only when the numphrases is a multiple of numberofgroups, each numphrases divided by numberofgroups days I have a repeated combination (same phrases in the same groups). I need to "shift" by 1 the phrases to get unique phrases for all groups in a 'numphrases' consecutive days. Please, test the function with 3 groups and 6 phrases to test the problem.